# run a python script on windows 7 client from linux using python

Tags: python, linux, windows

I'm new in python so my sincere apologies if this is a dum question.

I want to trigger, using python, from a linux server a python script run on an windows 7 client. This script get's the mouse pointer position, makes a screenshot of the desktop and in this screenshot draws an ellipse at the position determine above. I've searched over the internet for a solution but so far I didn't find a method. 
Is there a method to run the python script on the windows machine from linux?

Python script code that is on the windows machine:

```
    import win32api
    import wx
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    from os import sys     

    print "Step 1: Get Mouse position"
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()

    print "Step 2: Screenshot of the Desktop"
    ff=wx.App()
    screen = wx.ScreenDC()
    size = screen.GetSize()
    bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
    mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
    mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
    del mem
    bmp.SaveFile('screenshot.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
    im = bmp.ConvertToImage()

    print "Step 3: Draw an ellipse on the mouse pointer position"
    im2 = Image.open("screenshot_desktop.png")
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im2)
    r = 5
    draw.ellipse((x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r), fill="yellow")

    del draw
    im2.save("screenshot_mouse_position.png", "PNG")
```

Thanks,
Dragos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to start a python script on the windows machine whenever your linux's python script wants to.

To my knowledge, there is no easy way to do that.

One way would be to have a daemon listenning on a specific port on the windows machine that will trigger the script whenever it receive a certain command. This means you have to create a communication protocol over tcp/ip and watch for security.

Comment: Thanks Nico for your fast answer. Is there an easy way just to run the python script on windows from linux using python? I mean without the trigger mechanism from linux python script. I've looked at the subprocess from python, but from what I've read so far it seems that I can't open a subprocess on windows from a linux python script. And plink seems to work from windows to linux.

Comment: @user3241131 I've never heard of something like this possible without the way I describe.